# PHP optimize variable mapping

Tags: php, optimization, mapping

A function in my PHP is called with a parameter `$action`. This value can be `"on"` or `"off"`. What I need is to "map" this value to `1` or `0` respectively.

This is possible with:

```
if ($action === "on") {
    $value = 1;
else if ($action === "off") {
    $value = 0;
}
```

But this does not look nice and I think it can be optimized. I would like to see some function that performs this behavior something like this:

```
$value = varmap(array("on", "off"), array(1, 0), $action);
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to find a function that works something like this but maybe someone does know about it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you can easily go for ternary operator `$value = ($action == 'on') ? '1' : '0';`

Comment: I totally forgot about using that. Thanks! If you post it as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: if you want the results to be numeric use `$value = ($action == 'on') ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I used @raveenanigam's suggestion and changed it to numeric.

Answer (score 3):

Here I wrote the actual function for you, could be useful for me sometimes too:

```
<?php

function varmap($values, $outputValues, $input) {
    if(count($values) != count($outputValues)){
        return "Not the same count";    
    }

    foreach($values as $idx => $value) {
        if($value == $input){
            return $outputValues[$idx]; 
        }
    }
}

$action = "on";
$value = varmap(array("on", "off"), array(1, 0), $action);

echo $value; //Returns 1
```

Comment: Thanks, the other answers solved my particular problem but this answered my question best!

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you would have more states than off and on?

if not my suggestion is to do

```
$value = ($action == 'on') ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$value = ($action == 'on') ? '1' : '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand it to use more values then you can try this:

```
$data = array(
    'on'=>1,
    'off'=>2,
    'medium'=>3,
);

$to_check = 'on';
$my_var = '';

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === $to_check) {
        $my_var = $value;
        break;
    }
}

echo $my_var;
```

Result:

```
1
```